# Webpack 2: Director router is not working after compilation process

Tags: javascript, webpack

**What is the current behavior?**

It seems that some parts of director router constructor function are removed causing an unexpected error.

**NOTE**: This issue was not present in Webpack version 1.14.0.

**Reproduction**
https://github.com/marcalexiei/director-webpack-issue

Instructions in the readme.

There are two branches:

- "master" where the issue can be reproduced.
- "web-pack-1-14-0" has the previous version and has no errors.

**What is the expected behavior?**
No errors are generated and router init is a function.

**Configuration file**

```
    module.exports = {
      entry: {
        // app's entry point
        app: './src/app.js',

      },
      output: {
        publicPath: '/public/',
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        pathinfo: true,
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
      },
      resolve: {
        modules: [
          path.join(__dirname, './') , // frontend-app
          'node_modules'
        ],
        extensions: ['.js'],
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',

            exclude: /node_modules/,
          },
        ],
      },
    };
```

**System specs**

- Chrome 55.0.2883.95
- Safari 10.0.3
- Node 6.3.1
- Webpack 2.2.1
- MacOS 10.12.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR**: Add

```
resolve: {
  mainFields: ['browserify', 'browser', 'module', 'main']
}
```

to your config.

---

Explanation:

In webpack1 (https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-packagemains), the default value for that field was:

```
["webpack", "browser", "web", "browserify", ["jam", "main"], "main"]
```

However, in webpack2 (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-mainfields) the default value is:

```
["browser", "module", "main"]
```

Note that a few items are missing in webpack2 default values. In particular, `browserify` is not present.

This are the builds exported by director:

```
  "browserify": "./build/director",
  "main": "./lib/director",
```

`./build/director` is the browser compatible build, `./lib/director` is the node one. You have to tell webpack2 to use `./build/director`, hence the `"browserify"` entry in your config.